# Adding jQuery to act on the Select/Option that is dynamically created

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding `Select/Option` based on the user input.

How do I write a jQuery that reacts to `Select/Option` that is dynamically created based on user input.

Here is my jsfiddle,
https://jsfiddle.net/tnc5bqpw/2/

I tried adding the simple jQuery to react to new `Select/Option` whose id is `selecta`. But this does not work.

```
       // Select option for topic
        $("#selecta").change(function() {
        // varible to hold string
        console.log("changed");
        var str = "";
        var val = "";
        $("select option:selected").each(function() {
            str += $(this).text() + " ";
            val = $(this).val();
        });
        var divbox = document.getElementById('textbox');
        divbox.innerHTML ="<span style='color:black; font-family:Georgia,serif;font-size:30px;font-style:regular;'>Selected"+ str+"</span>";
        console.log(str,val);
        }).change();
```

Problem here :

I have a initial `Select/Option` and user gets to select two options. And based on this selection, new `Select/Option` is added to the page. I cannot figure out how can i added `jQuery change` trigger to this new `Select/Option`. Based on user's selection to this, page needs show other elements.

Comment: You want to add selected options based on another selection option?

Comment: yes! user selects one option and based on that other options appear.

Comment: Your question isn't clear, nether from here nor from fiddle.

Comment: Hi, I added some description, may be that helps

Comment: You need to use event delegation `$(document).on("change", ".selecta", function() ...`  (remember not to reuse IDs)

Comment: Wiritng code with proper indentation is the very first habbit you must learn.

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks a lot that worked! New to jQuery, so could not figure out the exact code for this. Here is the working version : https://jsfiddle.net/pb4y3q9v/4/

Comment: To be fair, many issues asked here are just not knowing the correct terminology to search for, so it's a fair question.  Just this gets asked *a lot*.